# Finding the number of terms needed to approximate a series with a given accuracy

Tags: calculus

Find the smallest number n of terms needed to obtain an approximation of the series

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 28 k e^{-0.45 k^2} \text { accurate to } 10^{-7}
\end{equation}

I understand that to find this number, I substitute (k+1) into k, I set the sum expression to be less than the accuracy, I simplify the inequality and the number rounded up to the nearest integer is the number of n terms required.

My issue is that I cannot simplify this expression after substituting k. My best guess is I have to use a natural log to get rid of e, but I'm not entirely certain. I'd love some help.

Comment: Approximate the remainder as $\int_n^\infty\, 28k e^{-0.45 k^2}\, dk$. The integral is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

$$28\,n\, e^{-\frac{9 }{20}n^2} =10^{-p}\quad\implies\quad 784 e^{-\frac{9 n^2}{10}} n^2 =10^{-2p}$$ Now, you are ready for Lambert function (let $n=\sqrt m$)
$$n=\frac{ \sqrt{10}}{3} \sqrt{-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{9}{7840 }10^{-2p}\right)}$$ and use $\lceil n \rceil$.

**Edit**

As @martycohen pointed out in comments, the real problem would be to find $n$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 28\,k\, e^{-\frac{9 }{20}k^2}-
\sum_{k=1}^n 28\,k\, e^{-\frac{9 }{20}k^2} \leq 10^{-p}$$but this would imply (!!) to know the infinite sum.

We can take into account that the sum and the integral are very highly correslated and then, as @Aruralreader commented, we can approximate th remainder by
$$R_n=\int_n^\infty  28\,k\, e^{-\frac{9 }{20}k^2} \,dk=\frac{280}{9} e^{-\frac{9 }{20}n ^2}$$

$$R_n < 10^{-p} \quad \implies \quad n>\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{3}  \sqrt{\log \left(\frac{280 }{9}10^p\right)}$$

Comment: That tells when the term is at the bound, not when the sum starting at the term is below the bound.

Comment: @martycohen. I fully agree with you. I did not want to argue with the OP and I just gave the solution of the equation (not the inequality). Cheers :-)